# how can i pass sql query to another page

Tags: php, sql, security, url

I'd like to pass sql query from one page to another page. I'd like to do this without security risk. İf i pass the query with get or post method it cause big security problems.

My aim is that:

I have a page that have some input boxes to search in data. When i click to button. It lists the records into a table. I want to present this table in another page without searching it again.

I think that i can do it using session variable but i dont think it is good way though.

How should i do that without security risks?

Comment: This is not a good practice. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: i have some inputs in my page. This inputs creates a sql query then list result into a table when i click the button. I want to pass this query to another page. Then list them again without using inputs.

Comment: Sounds like you are making a query builder? So, this question is more about saving state than anything else. Please update your question.

Comment: what language and/or framework are using?

Comment: -1 wow,  have you ever heard of **sql injection**?

Comment: @Shyju yeah a vulnerability is never "good practice",  but i would use stronger language,  like "suicidal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if somebody execute this

```
http://www.yourdomain.com?qry=delete from your users;--
```

Don't pass your query as a querystring value. You can post your input fields state / value to another form and you can build the query there **after sanitizing/verifying the input**.

Your approach is open for SQL injections.  You should better be taking care of that.

http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: But it may change in complex querys. For example when i use two or three table with "join"

Comment: @FURKANILGIN  : That does not matter. just have form fields for ehatever your search criteria and post that to another page and build your query with any number of tables.

Comment: -1 wow,  have you ever heard of **SQL INJECTION**?  There is nothing to sanitize...

Comment: down vote for what ? i did not entertain for this approach. I mentioned not use it.thats y i asked a question with that example to the op. However i forgot to mention abt sql injection in my answer. Will update to prevent future misleading.

Comment: @Rook : and it looks like the op edited his question. the original version has a sample which had a query which accepts a query.

Answer (score 2):

You just shouldn't do it ever. You may want to looking into using some form of RESTFUL web services.

Comment: i know. I shouldnt do it ever. But i dont know how cant i do it with best way. post sql or put in the session variable etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

create a function which includes the query, then call it from any page.

Comment: no i have some inputs in my page. This inputs creates a sql query when i click the button. I want to pass this query to another page.

Comment: You can always save the "inputs" in the session. Then you can pass these "inputs" to the function which contains the query.